# Meaning of spectral function of spin Green's function?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, spectroscopy, greens-functions

Since spins are neither bosons nor fermions, spin Green functions can be defined using either a commutator ($\eta=-1$) or an anticommutator ($\eta=1$), e.g., $$G_{ij,\eta}(t,t')=-i\theta(t-t')\langle[S_i^+,S_j^-]_\eta\rangle.$$ Both can be found in the literature.

However, what if one wants to consider observables related to, e.g., the density of states (DOS) of magnons or the like, which is reflected in the signal strength of optically probed peak structures?
Does the spectral function in real space $A_i(\omega)=-\mathrm{Im}\,G_{ii}$ or in $k$-space $A_k(\omega)=-\mathrm{Im}\,G_{k}$ have concrete physical meaning?

For fermions, such spectral functions are always positive and directly related to DOS. For bosons, at least we know that they are positive when $\omega>0$ and negative when $\omega<0$.

What about spins? How should one use spin Green functions to obtain such experimentally relevant information?